# How to play media?

Tags: android

Hi 
How to play media file in an application.I am trying it with the following code but do not know why it is not working for me

```
player= new MediaPlayer().create(context, R.raw.lonely);
player.start();
player.release();
```

Help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't played with `MediaPlayer`, but I would try without the `release()` call. [This example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-mediaplayer-example/) doesn't use it. And the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release()) say it's a cleanup method to be called after the playback:

> Releases resources associated with
>   this MediaPlayer object. It is
>   considered good practice to call this
>   method when you're done using the
>   MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're messing up the with constructors. You can instantiate the MediaPlayer statically: `MediaPlayer.create(Context context, int resid)`, which is the easiest way, cause you just need to call `play()`. Also you need a valid context, it's to say, if you're creating rhe MediaPlayer within an Activity or a Service, just pass "this" as a context.

You can also use the "normal" constructor `MediaPlayer()`, but then you would have to explicity call to `setDataSource()` and `prepare()` before `play()`.

Besides, as Grzegorz wrote, calling `release()` just after `play()` is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can folow this sample :

```
public void audioPlayer(String path, String fileName){
    //set up MediaPlayer    
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        mp.setDataSource(path+"/"+fileName);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.start();
}
```