# streaming mp3 from a url

Tags: android

i would like to listen an mp3 file from the web when i m clicking a btn!i was trying to use something like:

```
mp.setDataSource (http://....);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

but doesn't work..

also,i will have 10 btn that will do this job so i want to use prepare and stop in order to stop the mp3 if a second btn is pressed..please help!:)happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can provide some log entries, to see if there's any excepction, but just some basic... I guess you created the `MediaPlayer` object properly, didn't you?. I think we need more information.

Anyway, have a look to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644924/how-to-play-media/4645109#4645109) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647909/how-to-play-avi-video-with-android-2-2-sdk-in-java/4647945#4647945) you have a couple of samples.

Comment: thanks!of course i have added the MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer(); before...this is all into my onClick method..

Comment: Well, those three sentencies... that's the way its done, the link is working... Why don't you have a look to the log entries? Please provide more info

Comment: ok,now its working..but what do i have to add in order to stop and start the second song?

Answer (score 0):

Check this code for Video..should be similar for Audio as well.

```
    //Video 
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView01);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        // Set video link (mp4 format )
           //Uri video = Uri.parse("http://www.pocketjourney.com/downloads/pj/video/famous.3gp");
            //OR            
            //Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://<package>/" + R.raw.<resource>);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You May Use This

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://Yoururl.com/file.mp3");
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
    intent.setDataAndType(myUri, "audio/*"); 
    startActivity(intent);
```